# Ordering result with an IN restriction on Pk

Tags: cassandra

I'm inserting messages from multiple users and want to get last messages belonging to a sub-selection of users sorted in a descending order by the the "created" field.

MY TABLE (fetching messages via "user_id IN (...)"):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
        user_id timeuuid,
        created timestamp,

        msg text,
        PRIMARY KEY ((user_id), created)
    )
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC)
```

MY QUERY:

```
cqlsh:fb> SELECT user_id,created,msg FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (657818d6-9c7e-11e5-b392-978fb134d9c9,e2028f98-9c57-11e5-b96c-8863dfc615b7);
```

The result is sorted by "created" only within a set of messages per each "user_id", see below (red line dividing 2 different users).

However I want the whole result be sorted as "created DESC", i.e. "LAST ONE" should be on the top.

[image]

Please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by adding **order by clause** in your query, For example,

```
SELECT user_id,created,msg FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (657818d6-9c7e-11e5-b392-978fb134d9c9,e2028f98-9c57-11e5-b96c-8863dfc615b7) order by created DESC;
```

---

Here are the some different cases of query and their result explanation.

**Case 1:**
If you didn't provide the **order by** clause and **IN clause**, then it will work as following by default.

```
SELECT user_id,created,msg FROM posts;
```

The partition key order is based on your [partitioner type](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra_win/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archPartitionerAbout.html). In the above query `user_id` is the partition key, those partition key order is based on your partitioner type. So if your partitioner is Murmur3Partitioner then the result will be retrieved in hash order of `user_id` and the `created` column will be retrieved in `descending order with respect to the user_id`.

---

**Case 2:**
If you provide the partition key in **IN clause but not ORDER BY clause**.

```
SELECT user_id,created,msg FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (657818d6-9c7e-11e5-b392-978fb134d9c9,e2028f98-9c57-11e5-b96c-8863dfc615b7);
```

Then the result will be retrieved in the given order (order in which the query has in clause) of `user_id` partition key and `created` column will be in descending order with respect to the partition key.

---

You can dig more information if you are aware of how [CQL3 Maps to Cassandra's Internal Data Structure.(Refer slides from 43)](http://www.slideshare.net/DataStax/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure). But how ever if the [partition key is passed IN clause](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/) it will impact in the performance. Design your schema by considering these impacts too.

Comment: HI Jaya,

#1 is not working for me as I'm using manual pagination for the infinite scroll and as a result i'm getting an error 
_"Cannot page queries with both ORDER BY and a IN restriction on the partition key; you must either remove the ORDER BY or the IN and sort client side, or disable paging for this query"_

#2 won't work as well for my use-case. (have to submit as a 2nd comment - length)

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided more context. Building an analogue of a Facebook's wall: posts from friends are pulled as a single timeline, so my requirements come down to:
1. I should fetch posts for a specified set of friends, different for each user (hence tried IN).
2. Reverse sort order by time.
3. Need pagination.

Point about IN performance hit totally makes sense. 
Cannot wrap my head around a different approach and want to avoid building everything with a graph database.
Got a feeling I'm missing something simple & obvious...

Any thoughts are really appreciated!

Comment: Which version of cassandra and cassandra driver  are you using?

Comment: Cassandra 3.0, driver (I'm using Go): latest gocql = as of Dec 4. P.S. one of the approaches i'm testing now is to use an external index, ex. table in MySQL. I don't really like the idea of adding on more db, but anyways, please share your thoughts about this approach as well. Thanks!